# iOS: how to move ball

Tags: ios, uiview

Hi how do i create a moving ball on iOS.

- When the program starts, I will display the ball on the left of the screen. Subsequently, each time i click a `UIButton`, how do i move the ball to the right on the same x-axis.
- I managed to display the ball but how do i update and redraw its location when the `UIButton` is pressed? currently each time i press the `UIButton`, it creates a new ball and the old balls are not cleared.
- i understand its because i recreate a new instance of the ball. So how shall i go about fixing this?

---

Here is my code....

**ballView.m**

```
@implementation BallView

-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    }

    return self;
}

-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)dirtyRect
{
    NSLog(@"in drawRect");

    // Get the graphics context and clear it
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Draw a solid ball
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    CGContextFillEllipseInRect(ctx, dirtyRect);

    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

-(BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder
{
    return YES;
}
```

**MoveBallController.m**

```
-(void)moveBall
{

    CGRect viewFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);
    BallView *ball = [[BallView alloc] initWithFrame:viewFrame];
    [[self dotView] addSubview:ball];

}
```

Comment: As a general point, there are few cases where you need to use drawRect. As @rmaddy demonstrates, you can create a ball once, and move it's position simply by updating the frame.

Answer (score 3):

Create one `BallView` instance and store it in an instance variable. Then when the button is clicked you simply update the ball's frame:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGRect viewFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);
    _ball = [[BallView alloc] initWithFrame:viewFrame];
    [[self dotView] addSubview:_ball];
}

- (void)moveBall {
    CGRect frame = _ball.frame;
    frame.origin.x += 5; // use some appropriate increment
    _ball.frame = frame;
}
```

where `_ball` is your new instance variable.